Excel - Sum of rows that match a list of values in excel
Is there a way to use formula to find out the sum of multiple row values based on a list of referenced value? In the example below, is there a way that the "?" field could calculate automatically the sum of group 1 items. I hope to minimize the process and extra rows for calculation (as in image 1).

And further to the above example, how can i go further to include a coefficient of each type of the vegetables/groups subject to the group and also without the helper column and using only formula in the cell (as in image 2)


Assuming there is no Excel Constraints as per the posted tags, then could use one of the following, using GROUPBY() will simple and easy as well:


=DROP(GROUPBY(B3:B15,HSTACK(C3:C15,XLOOKUP(C3:C15,F3:F10,G3:G10,0)),HSTACK(ARRAYTOTEXT,SUM),,0),1)


• Or, if you don;t have access to GROUPBY() then with the existing layout try using the following with MAP()
=MAP(K9:K12,LAMBDA(x,SUM((x=B3:B15)*XLOOKUP(C3:C15,F3:F10,G3:G10,0))))


• Or another alternative not considering the words Groups instead splitting the fruits & veggies :
=SUM(SUMIF($F$3:$F$10,TEXTSPLIT(L3,", "),$G$3:$G$10))



Many thanks for the help, yes you are right, if not considering the words Groups, the third one works. But if i have a third dimension or i dont have the column L, I am not sure if would still work. My very initial target was actually not having L, which was just a helper column at the end of the day.

@ccnn all the solutions should work please try and let us know. The second one uses the Groups and the fruits + veggies as well, while the first one is one single dynamic array formula

@ccnn post your expected output and what you had tried, and hope you know that one question per post. Secondly what is the requirement for the min column?

like the second graph above i just added, for group 3, as an example, how do i get the apple cost x 2 + asparagus cost x 1, without the helper column.

@ccnn you have not read my comment clearly please show your attempt. what you have tried on your own
